# Multi-Gateway Routing - Fedora Kernel 3.17 & 3.18

Tags: networking, fedora, routing

I know the discussions on multi-gateway source (policy-based) routing have been hashed many times, but am yet find an answer to my current problem.

The server (running Fedora 21, Kernel 3.17 or 3.18) is connected via two NIC's, teamed using teamd-1.15-1 (Fedora Update), with six VLAN's built on the teamed interface (Team0).
The firewalld and NetworkManager daemons have been disabled, and I am not using IPTABLES, as I have a primary hardware firewall device.
Please don't ask why six VLAN's, it is a requirement for the network.

All six VLAN's function correctly when individually assigned as the default gateway, but my issue is how to have all six functioning as gateways for their individual VLAN traffic?

Thus far I have made the following setting changes to /usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-default.conf:

```
# Source route verification
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 0 (original default =1)
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 0 (original default =1)

# Accept IPv4 forwarding
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 (original default =0)

# Do not accept source routing
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0 (original default =1)
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0 (original default =1)
```

These changes are persistently & correctly reflected in /net/ipv4/conf files, etc.

The /iproute2/rt_tables file has been changed to reflect the required additional routing tables, as below:

```
#
# reserved values
#
255     local
254     main
253     default
205     EXTRAAPPS
204     DNSEXT
203     SERVEXT
202     INTRAAPPS
201     DNSINT
200     SERVINT
0       unspec
#
#       local
#
#1      inr.ruhep
```

The settings for one VLAN (vlan30, using routing table 200) are shown below, with IFCFG, ROUTE and RULE files shown:

**ifcfg-vlan30**

```
DEVICE=team0.30
PHYSDEV=team0
VLAN=yes
ONPARENT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
NM_CONTROLLED=no
DEFROUTE=yes
IPADDR1=192.168.129.67
NETMASK1=255.255.255.248
IPADDR0=192.168.129.66
NETMASK0=255.255.255.248
GATEWAY=192.168.129.65
```

**route-vlan30**

```
default table SERVINT via 192.168.129.50
192.168.129.64/29 dev team0.30 proto static scope global src 192.168.129.66 table SERVINT
```

**rule-vlan30**

```
from 192.168.129.66/32 table SERVINT
to 192.168.129.66/32 table SERVINT
from 192.168.129.67/32 table SERVINT
to 192.168.129.67/32 table SERVINT
```

The custom tables (200-205 inc) appear to be correct, as they show up in the /proc/etc/fib_trei file, as defined in the "route-vlanxx" file entries.

**FIB_TREI**

```
Id 200:
  +-- 0.0.0.0/0 1 0 0
     |-- 0.0.0.0
        /0 universe UNICAST
     |-- 192.168.129.64
        /29 universe UNICAST
Id 201:
  +-- 0.0.0.0/0 1 0 0
     |-- 0.0.0.0
         /0 universe UNICAST
     |-- 192.168.129.72
        /29 universe UNICAST
Id 202:
  +-- 0.0.0.0/0 1 0 0
     |-- 0.0.0.0
        /0 universe UNICAST
 |-- 192.168.129.80
        /29 universe UNICAST
Id 203:
  +-- 0.0.0.0/0 1 0 0
     |-- 0.0.0.0
        /0 universe UNICAST
     |-- 192.168.129.96
        /29 universe UNICAST
Id 204:
   +-- 0.0.0.0/0 1 0 0
     |-- 0.0.0.0
        /0 universe UNICAST
     |-- 192.168.129.104
        /29 universe UNICAST
Id 205:
   +-- 0.0.0.0/0 1 0 0
     |-- 0.0.0.0
        /0 universe UNICAST
     |-- 192.168.129.112
        /28 universe UNICAST
Main:
+-- 0.0.0.0/0 1 0 0
 |-- 0.0.0.0
    /0 universe UNICAST
 +-- 192.168.129.64/26 3 0 2
    |-- 192.168.129.64
       /29 link UNICAST
    |-- 192.168.129.72
       /29 link UNICAST
    |-- 192.168.129.80
       /29 link UNICAST
    |-- 192.168.129.96
       /29 link UNICAST
    |-- 192.168.129.104
       /29 link UNICAST
    |-- 192.168.129.112
       /28 link UNICAST
Local:
+-- 0.0.0.0/0 1 0 0
   +-- 127.0.0.0/8 1 0 0
      +-- 127.0.0.0/31 1 0 0
         |-- 127.0.0.0
            /32 link BROADCAST
            /8 host LOCAL
 (Snipped for brevity - not required for this matter)
```

The results from **ip addr, ip link and ip route** commands are shown below:

**ip addr**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master team0 state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:0a:f7:18:42:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet6 fe80::20a:f7ff:fe18:420c/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

3: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master team0 state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:0a:f7:18:42:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet6 fe80::20a:f7ff:fe18:420c/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

11: team0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
link/ether 00:0a:f7:18:42:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet6 fe80::20a:f7ff:fe18:420c/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

12: team0.30@team0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
link/ether 00:0a:f7:18:42:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.129.66/29 brd 192.168.129.71 scope global team0.30
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 192.168.129.67/29 brd 192.168.129.71 scope global secondary team0.30
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::20a:f7ff:fe18:420c/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

13: team0.31@team0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
link/ether 00:0a:f7:18:42:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.129.74/29 brd 192.168.129.79 scope global team0.31
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 192.168.129.75/29 brd 192.168.129.79 scope global secondary team0.31
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::20a:f7ff:fe18:420c/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

14: team0.32@team0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
link/ether 00:0a:f7:18:42:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.129.82/29 brd 192.168.129.87 scope global team0.32
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 192.168.129.83/29 brd 192.168.129.87 scope global secondary team0.32
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::20a:f7ff:fe18:420c/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

15: team0.36@team0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
link/ether 00:0a:f7:18:42:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.129.98/29 brd 192.168.129.103 scope global team0.36
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 192.168.129.99/29 brd 192.168.129.103 scope global secondary team0.36
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::20a:f7ff:fe18:420c/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

16: team0.37@team0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
link/ether 00:0a:f7:18:42:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.129.106/29 brd 192.168.129.111 scope global team0.37
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 192.168.129.107/29 brd 192.168.129.111 scope global secondary team0.37
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::20a:f7ff:fe18:420c/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

17: team0.38@team0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
link/ether 00:0a:f7:18:42:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.129.114/28 brd 192.168.129.127 scope global team0.38
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 192.168.129.115/28 brd 192.168.129.127 scope global secondary team0.38
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 192.168.129.120/28 brd 192.168.129.127 scope global secondary team0.38
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::20a:f7ff:fe18:420c/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**ip link**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00

2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master team0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:0a:f7:18:42:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

3: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master team0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:0a:f7:18:42:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

11: team0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
link/ether 00:0a:f7:18:42:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

12: team0.30@team0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
link/ether 00:0a:f7:18:42:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

13: team0.31@team0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
link/ether 00:0a:f7:18:42:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

14: team0.32@team0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
link/ether 00:0a:f7:18:42:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

15: team0.36@team0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
link/ether 00:0a:f7:18:42:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

16: team0.37@team0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
link/ether 00:0a:f7:18:42:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

17: team0.38@team0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
link/ether 00:0a:f7:18:42:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**ip route**

```
default via 192.168.129.113 dev team0.38 
192.168.129.64/29 dev team0.30  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.129.66 
192.168.129.72/29 dev team0.31  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.129.74 
192.168.129.80/29 dev team0.32  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.129.82 
192.168.129.96/29 dev team0.36  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.129.98 
192.168.129.104/29 dev team0.37  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.129.106 
192.168.129.112/28 dev team0.38  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.129.114
```

The routes in tables 200-205 inclusive have been set for "scope global" (shown as **Universe UNICAST** in /proc/net/fib_trei), as the addresses within these VLAN's need to be source-routed to a wide range of "as-yet" unknown destinations on the internet (via primary firewall router device), however the "ip route" command response shows the routes as being **scope link**, as it is in the MAIN table rather than **scope global** as defined in the custom route tables 200-205, and also in the **FIB_TREI** entries.

It appears to me that the Kernel is taking the MAIN IP table, rather than as described in the Fedora documents, that any tables and rules correctly defined and listed BEFORE, i.e. lower table ID number, should take precedence.

Is there anything I have missed that may be obvious in the settings of the default values, or something incorrect in the routing tables or rules that could correct this problem?

Any guidance, advice or hints would be greatly appreciated, before I tear out what little hair I have remaining.....

Cheers,
Garth.

Answer (score 0):

The finding was that the Fedora 21 and 22 "Server" install does not include the required files to enable fib_rules.c to run, which controls the multiple table rules.

The packages that are needed to make Policy Routing with multiple tables are:

kernel-headers, kernel-devel, and libnl3-devel

Once these were installed the policy routing works correctly.